# What descriptive variable name can I use here?

Tags: java, variables, struts, html-select

I'm creating a custom Java Struts tag that is for building and formatting an html select box in a standardised way (part of our usability guidelines).

Each select box has an additional/initial value which describes the requirement of the value returned by the select element, i.e.:

- *Mandatory* - with the label "Please Select"

  *Optional* - "None Selected"

  *Select All* - "Select All"

The custom tag will have a property that controls which of these are to be used.

So the problem is, I need to think of a variable name that can adequately explain that is is holding one of these three values!
I will be commenting the code in any case, but I'd prefer that co-workers didn't have to look up the source code to remember what the tag variable's purpose is.

**Edit:** To put some context around this problem, the usability strategy that I'm implementing here is that if there are more than 5 items that can be selected, the options should appear as a select box. 5 or less items will appear as radio buttons.
When radio buttons are being used, the mandatory label won't be displayed (form validation will complain if there's no value selected anyway).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**NOTE: See EDIT below for a different approach than the one given here**

How about `requirementConstraint`?

```
<my:customSelect requirementConstraint="Mandatory">
   <option value="1">A</option>
   <option value="2">B</option>
   <option value="3">C</option>
</my:customSelect>
```

Another possiblity is not to tri-state the value in the first place. For example, you can instead provide two separate properties: `required` (`"yes" | "no"`), and `selectAll` (`"yes" | "no"`) to make the intent clearer.

---

**EDIT**: Actually, I can see how a tri-state might still be useful, if I understand your requirements correctly. Another possibility would be to call the property `mustSelect` and make the allowed values `one` (mandatory), `any` (optional), and `all` (select all). Also, since "Select All" is a possibility, I'm assuming your `customSelect` tag renders each option as a checkbox. An example of how `mustSelect` might be used:

**Mandatory (at least one)**

```
<my:customSelect mustSelect="one">
   <option value="1">A</option>
   <option value="2">B</option>
   <option value="3">C</option>
</my:customSelect>
```

**Optional (zero or more)**

```
<my:customSelect mustSelect="any">
   <option value="1">A</option>
   <option value="2">B</option>
   <option value="3">C</option>
</my:customSelect>
```

**Select all**

```
<my:customSelect mustSelect="all">
   <option value="1">A</option>
   <option value="2">B</option>
   <option value="3">C</option>
</my:customSelect>
```

Comment: Thanks for the effort you put into this answer! 
See the edit to my post to explain why they won't be checkboxes.
The reason the tri-state exists is purely historical; they are mutually exclusive.

Answer (score 3):

'multiplicity' would seem the right name.

Looks like you're describing the following values:

Mandatory: 1
Optional: 0+
Select All: n

Answer (score 1):

That's an interesting question.  I must have come across this situation many times before, but never really thought about it in that way.

Your problem is that your programming language supports two-way options (e.g. zero-or-one) much better than three-way options (zero-one-or-many).  The shorthand that arises "naturally" is generally the shorthand that arises from the programming language, so there is no "natural" shorthand for three-way options.

In the spirit of KISS*, I suggest that you append "ZeroOneOrMany" to the property name.

---

[*] Keep It Simple, Stupid!

Answer (score 0):

**optionality**

Mandatory/Optional seems like a boolean whether this is an optional field.

Select All nearly seems unrelated and could be its own property.